# perl hash: operator expected errors

Tags: perl, hash, key, operators

I created a hash where the keys are the symbols of a phred+33 fastq file and the values are the associated fastq scores. I am getting a lot of errors relating to operators being expected throughout the entire code. The code runs fine without the hash portions.

Here is the code:

```
use warnings; 
use strict; 

open(IN, '<', '/path/to/in_file.txt') or die $!; 

my @symbols; 
my $count = 0; 
my %hash = (
    '!' => "0",  
    '"' => "1", 
    '#' => "2", 
    '$' => "3", 
    '%' => "4", 
    '&' => "5", 
    q(') => "6",
    '(' => "7", 
    ')' => "8", 
    '*' => "9", 
    '+' => "10", 
    ',' => "11", 
    '-' => "12", 
    '.' => "13", 
    '/' => "14", 
    '0' => "15", 
    '1' => "16", 
    '2' => "17", 
    '3' => "18", 
    '4' => "19", 
    '5' => "20", 
    '6' => "21", 
    '7' => "22", 
    '8' => "23", 
    '9' => "24", 
    ':' => "25", 
    ';' => "26", 
    '<' => "27", 
    '=' => "28", 
    '>' => "29", 
    '?' => "30", 
    '@' => "31", 
    'A' => "32", 
    'B' => "33", 
    'C' => "34", 
    'D' => "35", 
    'E' => "36", 
    'F' => "37", 
    'G' => "38", 
    'H' => "39", 
    'I' => "40", 
    'J' => "41", 
    'K' => "42"
);

while(my $fastq = <IN>){ 
    my $length = length $fastq;
    if ($length < 4180){ 
        next
    }
    my $substring = substr($fastq, 4175, 10);
    push(@symbols, $substring);
}
foreach (@symbols) { 
    my @eachsymbol = split //, $_;
    $count++;  
    print "Sequence ", $count, "\n"; 
    foreach my $symbol (@eachsymbol) { 
        if (exists $hash{$symbol}){
            print $hash{$symbol}, "\n"; 
        }
    } 
}
```

For reference, the input file looks like: 
!''*((((*+))%%%++)(%%%%).1*-+*''))**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `''' => "6",` should be `q(') => "6"`

Comment: I updated my answer that fixes another issue, that single-quotes won't interpolate a variable.

Comment: This ***`'$symbol'`*** ... looks for the literal string consisting of `$`, `s`, `y`, `m`, `b`, `o`, and `l` in the hash. Clearly, such a key does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you are creating hash keys that contain any non-word characters (ie. not `0-9a-zA-Z_`), you must quote them:

```
my $hash = (
    ';' => 1,
    '*' => 2,
    '!' => 'etc',
);
```

Same when you access/use them:

```
my $x = $hash{'!'};
```

Also, a variable will not interpolate when using single-quotes:

```
$hash{'$symbol'}
```

Change that to:

```
$hash{"$symbol"};
```

...or better:

```
$hash{$symbol};
```

Comment: Hi Stevieb, Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and was still unsuccessful. I will edit my question with your suggestions to show you what I did.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
''' => "6",
```

in your hash definition which is problematic. You can use `"'"` or `q{'}` instead.

You could also save yourself and the people whose help you are asking some eye damage by defining `%hash` as:

```
my %hash = qw(
    !  0 
    "  1
    #  2
    $  3
    %  4
    ....
    H 39
    I 40
    J 41
    K 42
);
```

or even better:

```
my @sym = qw( ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K );

my %symmap = map +($sym[$_] => $_), 0 .. $#sym;
```

This will result in the following warnings:

> Possible attempt to put comments in qw() list ...

and

> Possible attempt to separate words with commas ...

That's because the `qw` contains `#` and `,` characters. You can turn them off using

```
no warnings 'qw';
```

in the smallest applicable scope, as in

```
my %symmap;
{
    no warnings 'qw';
    my @sym = qw( ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K );
    %symmap = map +($sym[$_] => $_), 0 .. $#sym; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete other answers, note that you can build your hash using the ascii codes (in this way you avoid the quoting problems):

```
my %symmap = map { (chr($_), $_ - 33) } 33..75;
```